# Render partial twig in formmapper

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata

Is it possible to render a view into a formmapper?
The situation is like this:

```
 /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->tab('Company')
                ->with('Info')
                    ->add('name')
                ->end()
            ->end()

            ->tab('Abonnementen')
            ->with('Abonnementen', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
                //Render a partial twig here
            ->end()
        ;
    }
```

This is in my twig:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header"><h4 class="box-title">Abonnementen</h4></div>
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Active</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for abonnement in abonnementen %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ abonnement.name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ abonnement.description }}</td>
                                    <td>€ {{ abonnement.price }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ abonnement.id }}[active]"
                                                {% if abonnement.active %}
                                            checked="checked"
                                                {% endif %}>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" name="abonnement_save">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Is it even possible to load this into my tab in my formmapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is possible to do something similar. You want to inject your form into base sonata form. It is possible but at the end you get something like this:

```
  <form> # form from sonata
     <form> #your custom form
     </form>
  </form>
```

I don't recommend it.

Formmaper build form from formBuilder and you can define template(html) of your form field in standart way:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

I reccommend you to override sonata template name 'edit' and add there your code as another form.

```
 public function configure()
 {
      $this->setTemplate('edit', 'ApplicationM2MNewsletterBundle:CRUD:empty_form.html.twig');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I already fixed it, indeed in some way like this. For that; I will accept your answer.